# How to calculate AWS signature V4 in Swagger before request

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, swagger-ui

For our AWS API Endpoints we use AWS_IAM authorization and want to make a call from Swagger UI. 
To make a successful call there must be 2 headers 'Authorization' and 'x-amz-date'. To form 'Authorization' we use [following steps from aws doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html).
We must to change 'x-amz-date' with every call to go through authorization.
The question is: How to write script in Swagger to sign request, which run every time **before** request send to aws?
(We know how to specify both headers one time before loading Swagger page, but this process should be re-run **before every** call).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We're using API Gateway as well as Swagger to define the APIs and have also been trying to figure out how to both generate the JS SDK using swagger-codegen (looks like the API Gateway console has a feature or custom template that includes the sigv4 code in the templated code) and then embed that sigv4 extra sauce into the swagger docs JS code, ie: on `ApiClient.js` `applyAuthToRequest` switch case.

Comment: I suppose the swagger doc generation tool works in a similar way to swagger codegen that enables additional (ie: mustache) templates to customize the output with different markup, scripts, etc?

Comment: guessing one option would be to fork `swagger-ui` (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) and include the same sigv4 magic there?

Comment: Yeah according to their [docs](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#customize) that seems to be the way to go. Wondering what that `authorizations` parameter you can initialize it can do if passing `sigv4` there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is built-in support in [swagger-js](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js) to add `requestInterceptor`s to do just this.  The swagger-ui project uses swagger-js under the hood.

Simply create a request interceptor like such:

```
requestInterceptor: {
  apply: function (request) {
    // modify the request object here
    return request;
  }
}
```

and apply it to your swagger instance on creation:

```
window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
  url: url,
  dom_id: "swagger-ui-container",
  requestInterceptor: requestInterceptor,
```

Here you can set headers in the `request` object (note, this is not the *standard* javascript http request object, inspect it for details).  But you do have access to all headers here, so you can calculate and inject them as needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can pretty easily monkeypatch signing from the AWS SDK into SwaggerJS(and thus SwaggerUI). See [here](https://medium.com/@Prestomation/swaggerjs-api-explorer-using-aws-sigv4-authentication-on-amazon-api-gateway-2883f66f35c1)

I have a slightly modified SwaggerUI [here](http://prestomation-blog-demos.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/swagger/index.html#/default). Given some AWS credentials and an API ID, it will pull down the Swagger definition, display it in SwaggerUI, and then you can call the API using sigv4.

The Authorizer implementation looks like this:

```
var AWSSigv4RequestSigner = function(credentialProvider, aws) {
  this.name = "sigv4";
  this.aws = aws;
  this.credentialProvider = credentialProvider;
};

AWSSigv4RequestSigner.prototype.apply = function(options, authorizations) {
  var serviceName = "execute-api";

  //If we are loading the definition itself, then we need to sign for apigateway.
  if (options && options.url.indexOf("apigateway") >= 0) {
    serviceName = "apigateway";
  }

  if(serviceName == "apigateway" || (options.operation && options.operation.authorizations && options.operation.authorizations[0].sigv4))
  {
    /**
     * All of the below is an adapter to get this thing into the right form for the AWS JS SDK Signer
     */
    var parts = options.url.split('?');
    var host = parts[0].substr(8, parts[0].indexOf("/", 8) - 8);
    var path = parts[0].substr(parts[0].indexOf("/", 8));
    var querystring = parts[1];

    var now = new Date();
    if (!options.headers)
    {
     options.headers = [];
    }

    options.headers.host = host;
    if(serviceName == "apigateway")
    {
      //For the swagger endpoint, apigateway is strict about content-type
      options.headers.accept = "application/json";
    }

    options.pathname = function () {
      return path;
    };
    options.methodIndex = options.method;
    options.search = function () {
      return querystring ? querystring : "";
    };
    options.region = this.aws.config.region || 'us-east-1';

    //AWS uses CAPS for method names, but swagger does not.
    options.method = options.methodIndex.toUpperCase();

    var signer = new this.aws.Signers.V4(options, serviceName);


    //Actually add the Authorization header here
    signer.addAuthorization(this.credentialProvider, now);

    //SwaggerJS/yourbrowser complains if these are still around
    delete options.search;
    delete options.pathname;
    delete options.headers.host;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};
```