# Swagger with AWS IAM user Access Key/Secret

Tags: swagger, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I am trying out AWS API Gateway, and it's very easy to import/export API definition from Swagger.

However, I've set my API to require AWS_IAM authorization so it's not public. But I cannot find how to make it work with Swagger UI. It seems Swagger UI only takes API Key, instead of IAM user's Access Key and Secret for Sigv4 signing.

Does anyone know is there a way to configure Swagger UI to take in Access Key/Secret, and sign the request for AWS_IAM auth?

Any direction would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Swagger UI OOTB does not support AWS_IAM auth, however, there you can still accomplish Sigv4 Signing. [How to calculate AWS signature V4 in Swagger before request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36336072/5787099) gives two good examples on how to accomplish this.

I used the [second example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43240312/5787099), in conjunction with the author's [blog](https://medium.com/@Prestomation/swaggerjs-api-explorer-using-aws-sigv4-authentication-on-amazon-api-gateway-2883f66f35c1) post to test with multiple user Access Key/Secrets. The blog post also goes into more detail on using the AWS JS SDK for this purpose.